# Determine whether a product can be purchased based on the stock status of another product in WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, product, stock

I have an WooCommerce shop with 3 different products (IDs 6241, 6242 and 6243) and I'm trying to make a product purchasable only if the previous product is out of stock.

Which comes down to:

- While ID 6241 is in stock > ID 6242 is not purchasable
- When ID 6241 is out of stock > ID 6242 become purchasable
- While ID 6242 is in stock > ID 6243 is not purchasable
- When ID 6242 is out of stock ID 6243 become purchasable
- Et cetera..

---

I succeed to do that with 2 different products, but now I'm trying to make a loop so I can apply that through multiple products (at the end, I should have 6 different products).

So I write a loop to go through my 3 current products:

```php
add_filter('woocommerce_is_purchasable', '_is_stage_purchasable', 10, 2);
function _is_stage_purchasable($is_purchasable, $product) {
        $product_id = array(6241,6242,6243); //array with product IDs
        foreach($product_id as $id){ //loop through products
            if( $product->id==$id && $product->get_stock_quantity() == 0 ){ //if product = product N and product N stock = 0
                $value = $id + 1; //value = next product ID
                $product = new WC_Product( $value );
                return true; //set new product as purchasable
            }else{ //if product = product N and product N stock > 0
                $value = $id + 1; //value = next product ID
                $product = new WC_Product( $value );
                return false; //set new product as not purchasable
            }
        }      
}
```

But I'm facing some issues. Using this code makes the products 6242 and 6243 not purchasable if 6241 is out of stock. I don't understand why? Could someone give me some hints on that issue?

Answer (score 0):

Your code contains some mistakes:

- It is not necessary to loop through your products ID's array, as the hook is executed separately for each product
- `$product->id` is replaced by `$product->get_id(`) since WooCommerce 3.0+
- You use `$value = $id + 1` while it is actually about obtaining the previous product object, so -1 seems the right way
- Via `get_stock_status()` you can determine the status of the previous product and based on that make the current product purchasable

So you get:

```php
// Is purchasable
function filter_woocommerce_is_purchasable( $purchasable, $product ) {
    // Array with product IDs
    $product_ids = array( 6241, 6242, 6243 );

    // Get current product ID
    $current_product_id = $product->get_id();

    // Only for specific products
    if ( in_array ( $current_product_id, $product_ids ) ) {
        // By default NOT purchasable
        $purchasable = false;

        // Calculate previous product ID
        $previous_product_id = $current_product_id - 1;

        // Get previous product object
        $previous_product = wc_get_product( $previous_product_id );
        
        // Is a WC product 
        if ( is_a( $previous_product, 'WC_Product' ) ) {
            // Get stock status
            if ( $previous_product->get_stock_status() == 'outofstock' ) {
                // Make purchasable
                $purchasable = true;
            }
        }
    }

    return $purchasable;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_is_purchasable', 'filter_woocommerce_is_purchasable', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: It's perfect ! Thank you so much ! I know there's some mistakes in the code i wrote but i have 0 dev background so i'm trying to learn day after day and your message really helped me with new things i did not know !

Big thanks :)